# Spark: Getting N elements from a RDD, .take() or .filterByRange()?

Tags: performance, apache-spark

I have a RDD called `myRdd:RDD[(Long, String)]` (`Long` is an index which it was got using `zipWithIndex()`) with a number of elements but I need to cut it to get a specific number of elements for the final result.

I am wondering which is better way to do this:

```
myRdd.take(num)
```

or

`myRdd.filterByRange(0, num)`

I don't care about the order of the selected elements, but I do care about the performance.

Any suggestions? Any other way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try and measure? Then you may have noted something, but I see the answer below as well now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`take` is an action, and `filterByRange` is a transformation. An action sends the results to the driver node, and a transformation does not get executed until an action is called.

The `take` method will take the first `n` elements of the RDD and will send it back to the driver. The `filterByRange` a little bit more sophisticated, since it will take those element whose key is between the specified bounds.

I'd say that there are not so many differences in terms of performance between them. If you just want to send the results to the driver, without caring about the order, use the `take` method. However, if you want to benefit of the distributed computation and you don't need to send results back to the driver, use `filterByRange` method and then call to the action.